# Fullcalendar event filter with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to filter events with checkboxes. I tried this (Based on this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29993265/4876591)

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {

        return ['all', event.state].indexOf(function(){
                    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
                    return $(this).val()
               });
        }) >= 0;           
}
```

On change event:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
   $('#mycalendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
}
```

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="estado" value="all">All
<input type="checkbox" name="estado" value="0">Open
<input type="checkbox" name="estado" value="1">Close
```

Any advice with this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain the question rather than post a link to it.

Comment: `$('input[type="checkbox"]')` and you have radios https://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/ - use `$('input[type="radio"]')`

Comment: my bad, just typo trying to do it with radios

Comment: not yet, i make a mistake when i wrote the question