# FullCalendar 4.0.0-beta.2 calling eventRender function from another, non-calendar function

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, filtering, project, fullcalendar-4

I am trying to integrate FullCalendar 4.0.0-beta.2 in my project, and one of the buttons I need is filtering the results based on a certain event parameter ("name" in this case). I have the functionality for the "My Events Only" button, which will set the boolean `isShowAll` correctly. The issue I am having is making the function `myEventFunc` call the function `eventRender`. Using `calendar.rerenderEvents();` does not seem to work either.

I am relatively new to JavaScript, so if there is a simple solution, I would prefer it. If there is another (much better) solution to my entire goal of filtering the results based on a given name, please explain it well! Thanks :)

calendar.html:

```
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />

  <!-- Modal display files-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/modalstyle.css">

  <!-- FullCalendar packages -->
  <link href='../packages/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='../packages/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='../packages/timegrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='../packages/list/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <script src='../vendor/rrule.js'></script>
  <script src='../packages/core/main.js'></script>
  <script src='../packages/interaction/main.js'></script>
  <script src='../packages/daygrid/main.js'></script>
  <script src='../packages/timegrid/main.js'></script>
  <script src='../packages/list/main.js'></script>
  <script src='../packages/rrule/main.js'></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

  <script>
    var isShowAll = true;
    var thisOwner = "Pranay Agrawal";

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      // TODO turn PHP variable into javascript?
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'rrule'],

        /*The bar on the top of the calendar for navigation*/
        header: {
          /*left: 'prev,next today',*/
          left: 'today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'timeGridOneWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek',

        },

        /*Custom views*/
        views: {
          timeGridOneWeek: {
            type: 'timeGrid',
            duration: {
              days: 7
            },
            buttonText: 'week'
          },
          listWeek: {
            duration: {
              days: 7
            }
          }
        },
        slotLabelInterval: {hours: 1}, //slots labeled by one hour
        selectOverlap: false, //user not allowed to "select" periods of times that are occupied by events
        defaultView: 'timeGridOneWeek', //start on week view
        slotDuration: '00:15:00', //each hour is split into 15 minutes
        minTime: "06:00:00", //start day 6am
        maxTime: '23:00:00', //end day 11pm
        scrollTime: '11:30:00', //start view at 11:30am?
        allDaySlot: false, //cannot make allday events
        nowIndicator: true, //red bar that shows current time
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        weekNumbersWithinDays: true, //styling week numbers in dayGrid view
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

        events: [{
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2019-02-01'
          },
          {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2019-02-07',
            end: '2019-02-10'
          },
          {
            groupId: 999,
            id: 2,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2019-02-09T16:00:00'
          },
          {
            groupId: 999,
            id: 2,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2019-02-16T16:00:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Conference',
            id: 2,
            start: '2019-02-11',
            end: '2019-02-13'
          },
          {
            title: 'Dunkin\' Donuts',
            start: '2019-03-17T10:30:00',
            end: '2019-03-17T11:15:00',
            color: '#800080'
          },
          {
            title: 'AppleBee\'s',
            start: '2019-03-22T15:00:00',
            end: '2019-03-22T16:30:00',
            location: 'The Arena',
            color: '#ff0000',
            description: 'Big Event',
            owner: 'Pranay Agrawal'
          },
          {
            title: 'Mellow Mushroom',
            start: '2019-03-19T13:30:00',
            color: '#cc3300'
          },
          {
            title: 'India Oven',
            start: '2019-03-20T16:30:00',
            color: '#cc9900'
          },
          {
            title: 'Thai Thai',
            start: '2019-03-21T12:00:00',
            color: '#669900'
          },
          {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: '2019-02-13T07:00:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            url: 'http://google.com/',
            start: '2019-02-24T12:05:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Free Pizza',
            allday: 'false',
            borderColor: "#5173DA",
            color: '#99ABEA',
            location: '3rd Floor Boys',
            textColor: "#000000",
            description: "<p>This is just a fake description for the Free Pizza.</p><p>Nothing to see!</p>",
            start: '2019-03-16T12:05:00',
            end: '2019-03-16T12:55:00',
            owner: 'Jason Tran'
          }
        ],

      eventRender: function(info) {
        window.alert("eventRender called: " + isShowAll);
        if(isShowAll) { //show all events
          return true;
        }
        else if(info.event.extendedProps.owner!=thisOwner) { //if an event is not the owner's, remove it from display!
          return false;
        }
      },

        eventClick: function(info) {
          /* Change modal html text dependent on event information*/
          document.getElementById("myTitle").innerHTML = info.event.title;
          document.getElementById("myLoc").innerHTML = info.event.extendedProps.location;
          document.getElementById("myDesc").innerHTML = info.event.extendedProps.description;
          document.getElementById("myTime").innerHTML = info.event.start + " - " + info.event.end;

          /* Functionality for displaying and removing modal on click*/
          var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
          var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
          modal.style.display = "block"; //show the modal display
          span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
          }
          window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
              modal.style.display = "none";
            }
          }

        }
      });
      calendar.render();
    });

  function myEventFunc() {

    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
      if (checkBox.checked == true){
        isShowAll=false;
      } else {
        isShowAll=true;
      }
      window.alert("myEventFunc called: " + isShowAll);
      //calendar.rerenderEvents();

    }

  </script>

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 40px 10px;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    #calendar {
      max-width: 900px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    /* cursor pointer when hovering events */
    .fc-event,
    .fc-list-item {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .e1Div {
    background-color: #99ABEA;
    color: #000;
    border: solid 1px #5173DA;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="e1Div">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onClick="myEventFunc()" />
    <label for="e1">My Events Only</label>
</div>

  <div id='calendar'></div>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h2 id='myTitle'>Modal Header</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id='myTime'>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
        <p id='myDesc'>Some other text...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <h3 id='myLoc'>Modal Footer</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you can't call eventRender directly, it's a callback option - so you supply a function to be executed at a later point when a certain point is reached in the process of displaying the calendar (i.e. we're about to draw an event on the calendar, in this case). It gets executed by fullCalendar's code in response to a pre-defined situation, it's not something you can directly cause to execute manually.

Comment: In theory calling rerenderEvents() should cause all the events to be re-drawn, which in turn should cause the eventRender callback to be executed once for each event which is going to be displayed. You didn't say what went wrong when you tried to execute that (a console error or something, perhaps?), but I'd guess that maybe `calendar` is undefined inside myEventFunc() because you only declare it within the scope of the DomContentLoaded callback, and myEventFunc is outside that scope. Did you check for errors when you were testing it?

Comment: P.S. are you aware you have included jQuery in your page but are not actually using it, as far as I can see? You can probably remove that reference.

Comment: Is there a way to define the calendar outside the function then or force an update? I did not see an error while testing - nothing just happened. I saw two examples online (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641355/jquery-fullcalendar-event-filtering) and (http://www.mikesmithdev.com/demo-fullcalendar-with-event-filtering/) but it used different stuff like jquery and an older version of the fullcalendar, which I found difficult to translate.

Comment: You can define the _variable_ outside the function so it's a global. Or you could move the other functions inside the block. Although if you don't have any console errors that's a bit odd

Comment: What I mean is something like `var calendar 
= null; document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      // TODO turn PHP variable into javascript?
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

      calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {`...etc. So now the calendar variable has scope outside the DOMContentLoaded event.

Comment: Dang, I really just forgot the basics of programming - declaring something as null. It works now! Thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access calendar in your function, you can do something like this.

```
<script>
    var isShowAll = true;
    var thisOwner = "Pranay Agrawal";
    var calendars = {};

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        // TODO turn PHP variable into javascript?
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'rrule'],

            /*The bar on the top of the calendar for navigation*/
            header: {
                /*left: 'prev,next today',*/
                left: 'today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'timeGridOneWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek',

            },

            /*Custom views*/
            views: {
                timeGridOneWeek: {
                    type: 'timeGrid',
                    duration: {
                        days: 7
                    },
                    buttonText: 'week'
                },
                listWeek: {
                    duration: {
                        days: 7
                    }
                }
            },
            slotLabelInterval: {hours: 1}, //slots labeled by one hour
            selectOverlap: false, //user not allowed to "select" periods of times that are occupied by events
            defaultView: 'timeGridOneWeek', //start on week view
            slotDuration: '00:15:00', //each hour is split into 15 minutes
            minTime: "06:00:00", //start day 6am
            maxTime: '23:00:00', //end day 11pm
            scrollTime: '11:30:00', //start view at 11:30am?
            allDaySlot: false, //cannot make allday events
            nowIndicator: true, //red bar that shows current time
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            weekNumbersWithinDays: true, //styling week numbers in dayGrid view
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

            events: [{
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2019-02-01'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: '2019-02-07',
                    end: '2019-02-10'
                },
                {
                    groupId: 999,
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2019-02-09T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    groupId: 999,
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2019-02-16T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Conference',
                    id: 2,
                    start: '2019-02-11',
                    end: '2019-02-13'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Dunkin\' Donuts',
                    start: '2019-03-17T10:30:00',
                    end: '2019-03-17T11:15:00',
                    color: '#800080'
                },
                {
                    title: 'AppleBee\'s',
                    start: '2019-03-22T15:00:00',
                    end: '2019-03-22T16:30:00',
                    location: 'The Arena',
                    color: '#ff0000',
                    description: 'Big Event',
                    owner: 'Pranay Agrawal'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Mellow Mushroom',
                    start: '2019-03-19T13:30:00',
                    color: '#cc3300'
                },
                {
                    title: 'India Oven',
                    start: '2019-03-20T16:30:00',
                    color: '#cc9900'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Thai Thai',
                    start: '2019-03-21T12:00:00',
                    color: '#669900'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: '2019-02-13T07:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                    start: '2019-02-24T12:05:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Free Pizza',
                    allday: 'false',
                    borderColor: "#5173DA",
                    color: '#99ABEA',
                    location: '3rd Floor Boys',
                    textColor: "#000000",
                    description: "<p>This is just a fake description for the Free Pizza.</p><p>Nothing to see!</p>",
                    start: '2019-03-16T12:05:00',
                    end: '2019-03-16T12:55:00',
                    owner: 'Jason Tran'
                }
            ],

            eventRender: function (info) {
                window.alert("eventRender called: " + isShowAll);
                if (isShowAll) { //show all events
                    return true;
                } else if (info.event.extendedProps.owner != thisOwner) { //if an event is not the owner's, remove it from display!
                    return false;
                }
            },

            eventClick: function (info) {
                /* Change modal html text dependent on event information*/
                document.getElementById("myTitle").innerHTML = info.event.title;
                document.getElementById("myLoc").innerHTML = info.event.extendedProps.location;
                document.getElementById("myDesc").innerHTML = info.event.extendedProps.description;
                document.getElementById("myTime").innerHTML = info.event.start + " - " + info.event.end;

                /* Functionality for displaying and removing modal on click*/
                var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
                var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
                modal.style.display = "block"; //show the modal display
                span.onclick = function () {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }
                window.onclick = function (event) {
                    if (event.target == modal) {
                        modal.style.display = "none";
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        calendars.calendar = calendar;
        calendar.render();           

    });
    function myEventFunc() {

            var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
            if (checkBox.checked == true) {
                isShowAll = false;
            } else {
                isShowAll = true;
            }
            window.alert("myEventFunc called: " + isShowAll);
            console.log(calendars.calendar);
            calendars.calendar.rerenderEvents();

        }

</script>
```