# How to filter events in the new v5 of Fullcalendar.io

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

**version 4** had `eventRender` and was quite easy to render or not an event as all you had to do [was return `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29993265/28004)

with version 5 (currently on beta 4), that event was replaced with `eventContent` and `eventClassNames` but I'm struggling to replicate the same idea, so I can easily show resources with and without events in a **timeline view**

[from the upgrade guide](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/upgrading-from-v4#event-rendering) it says:

> `eventContent` - for if you injected DOM content via eventRender. **You cannot cancel rendering by returning false** however. Instead, attached a `display:'none'` property on the Event Input.

but if in that event I do that, it still shows the event:

```js
eventContent: (arg) => {
   arg.event.display = 'none'
}
```

[image]

what am I missing? What should we return/setup so the event is no longer shown?

---

I've also tried

```js
eventContent: (arg) => {
   return { display: 'none' }
}
```

but all it does is hide the content of the event itself, does not remove the event, and I end up having the event "frame"

[image]

Comment: what are you actually trying to do? Surely if you want to filter events it would make sense to add/remove the events themselves from the calendar, rather than just prevent them being displayed?

Comment: @ADyson as there's a lot of events visible, I simply want to, upon a button, toggle (show/hide) only relevant events... I do not want to keep fetching events from the source, as I already have them all... BTW, a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5515) was opened about my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While a possible solution was discussed [here](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5515), you can also exploit the new `eventClassNames` method:

```js
eventClassNames(args) {
   return args.extendedProps.visible ? "" : "event-hidden";
}
```

then define a CSS rule

```css
.event-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Upgrade guide](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4) now mentions:

> eventContent - for if you injected DOM content via eventRender. You
> cannot cancel rendering by returning false however. Instead, make sure
> your event object has its display property set to 'none' before
> eventContent executes. You can do this dynamically by setting
> event.setProp('display', 'none').

So two parts:

- setting property is done using `event.setProp('display','none')`,
  `event.display = none` will not work
- this needs to be done before `eventContent`, so e.g. `eventDidMount`

```
eventDidMount: function(info) {
  if (...) {
    info.event.setProp('display','none')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new `batchRendering` function to do this as well eg.

```
vm.rerenderEvents = ->
    vm.calendar.batchRendering ->
      vm.calendar
        .getEvents()
        .forEach (event) ->
          visible = checkFilters event

          if not visible
            event.setProp 'display', 'none'
          else
            event.setProp 'display', 'auto'

          return
        return
      return
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I was able to hide event itself(box) by changing "display" attribute.

```
eventContent: function(info) {
  var event = info.event;
  event.setProp('display', 'none');
},
```